# How to Fix MVC Cannot create/shadow copy 'XXX' when that file already exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Several times a day I receive this error while running my MVC 4 Razor project. when i refresh the page it will be solved for only that time. What is the permanent solution of that.

```
Cannot create/shadow copy 'WebGrease' when that file already exists.
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and then rebuilding? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue there are two approaches.

**Solution 1:**
Restart the IIS and Restart the AppPool in which the virtual directory exists.

**Solution 2:**
You have to tell ASP.NET MVC not to shadow copy the project assemblies to the ASP.NET temporary folders file by updating your web.config with the following entry:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then restart your application.

**Reason:**
By default shadow copy is enabled on every appdomain created by ASP.NET MVC. Assemblies loaded will be copied to a shadow copy cache directory, and will be used from there. So that the original file is not locked and can be modified. An error you may encounter when running ASP.Net apps with the debugger is “Cannot create/shadow copy ‘XXX’ when that file already exists”.

Answer (score 0):

here is a work around

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/06/09/cannot-createshadow-copy-file-name-when-that-file-already-exists/

i haven't tried this though!